# curly brackets in url will not pass through validation vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url, curly-braces

i have this url, http://www.poer.com/oneup.htm?zip={zip}.
I need the {zip}, because in my code, when this page opens, I replace the {zip} with a zipcode say 10001. 
But in aspx, when i put validation for that txtbox, it wont let the {} pass through.
This is the validation - ValidationExpression="http://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?"
regularexpressionvalidator.
How can i get the curly brackets in sql server? which is my db in backend

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `ValidationExpression` but it looks like just a regex so can't you just add the `={zip}` to the end of it?

```
ValidationExpression="http://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?={zip}"
```